# JS building Error caused by Shopware Paypal Module

Tags: shopware, shopware6

since I installed the SwagPayPal module via composer I am getting the following error when building the storefront using `build-storefront.sh`:

```
ERROR in /var/www/html/content/web/vendor/store.shopware.com/swagpaypal/src/Resources/app/storefront/src/swag-paypal.abstract-buttons.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '@paypal/paypal-js' in '/var/www/html/content/web/vendor/store.shopware.com/swagpaypal/src/Resources/app/storefront/src'
```

Does anybody know what causes this and how to fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In a shell navigate to `/var/www/html/content/web/vendor/store.shopware.com/swagpaypal/src/Resources/app/storefront/src` and run

```bash
npm install
```

Then try building the storefront again.

Comment: Shouldn't that happen in build-storefront.sh automatically?

Comment: Thank you, dneustadt, it solves the problem. However, I agree with Alex, why doesn't it happen automatically? Interestingly, it is working within our CD, the problem occurs on my local dev env only.

Answer (score 0):

I observed 3 different reasons for problems like this:

## `jq` not installed

`bin/build-storefront.sh` and `bin/build-administration.sh` should install this for you. but only if commandline tool `jq` is installed and file `var/plugins.json` is correct.
here is the part of this this script that installs the npm dependencies if `jq` is installed:

```
if [[ $(command -v jq) ]]; then
    OLDPWD=$(pwd)
    cd "$PROJECT_ROOT" || exit

    jq -c '.[]' "var/plugins.json" | while read -r config; do
        srcPath=$(echo "$config" | jq -r '(.basePath + .storefront.path)')

        # the package.json files are always one upper
        path=$(dirname "$srcPath")
        name=$(echo "$config" | jq -r '.technicalName' )

        if [[ -f "$path/package.json" && ! -f "$path/node_modules" && $name != "storefront" ]]; then
            echo "=> Installing npm dependencies for ${name}"

            if [[ -f "$path/package-lock.json" ]]; then
                npm clean-install --prefix "$path"
            else
                npm install --prefix "$path"
            fi
        fi
    done
    cd "$OLDPWD" || exit
else
    echo "Cannot check extensions for required npm installations as jq is not installed"
fi
```

## `SHOPWARE_SKIP_BUNDLE_DUMP` prevents `plugins.json` update

if `jq` is installed than maybe your `plugins.json` is not up to date. if env variable `SHOPWARE_SKIP_BUNDLE_DUMP` is defined, this will prevent this file from being updated.

## wrong `npm` version

From Version 5 to 6 `swag/paypal` will not build with too old npm version installed. I had `npm@6` installed and got errors. After switching to `npm@9` everything builds well.

Especially because you wrote:

> it is working within our CD

It may be this kind of wrong version.